# List all the application pools in inno setup

Tags: asp.net, inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup to create a installer for an ASP.net application. I would like to have a ComboBox with all the application pools in system. I have found the following part of code to get all the application pools:

```
IIS := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');
appPools := IIS.GetObject('IIsApplicationPools', 'localhost/W3SVC/AppPools');
```

I also have found how to get single particular application pool, but I am not able to figure out how to iterate through this appPools.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. It requires using external package named WMI. It can be downloaded from http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=WMI. Heere is a full code:

```
appPools := IIS.GetObject('IIsApplicationPools', 'localhost/W3SVC/AppPools');

IISPoolIndex := 1;

WebSite := IIS.GetObject('IIsWebService', 'localhost' + '/w3svc');
// GetObject structure: Schema, NextName of data
tVariants := ComEnumerate(WebSite.GetObject('IIsApplicationPools', 'AppPools'));
 For i := 0 to GetArrayLength (tVariants) - 1 do
 begin
 // ComboBox with Application Pool Names
 AppPoolsComboBox.Items.Add(tVariants[i].Name);
end;
```

Comment: WMI is a core Windows management technology rather than external package. However, for your particular task you need an external library (e.g. the one from that site) to get support for enumerators which you can't implement in Inno Setup's Pascal Script at this time.